# What is difference between pop vs pop2 instructions in jvm?

Tags: java, jvm

I Refered the below oracle jvm doc

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.pop

> **pop** Operation Pop the top operand stack value
>
> Format
>
> pop Forms pop = 87 (0x57)
>
> Operand Stack ..., value →
>
> ...
>
> Description Pop the top value from the operand stack.
>
> The pop instruction must not be used unless value is a value of a
>   category 1 computational type (§2.11.1).
>
> **pop2** Operation Pop the top one or two operand stack values
>
> Format
>
> pop2 Forms pop2 = 88 (0x58)
>
> Operand Stack Form 1:
>
> ..., value2, value1 →
>
> ...
>
> where each of value1 and value2 is a value of a category 1
>   computational type (§2.11.1).
>
> Form 2:
>
> ..., value →
>
> ...
>
> where value is a value of a category 2 computational type (§2.11.1).
>
> Description Pop the top one or two values from the operand stack.

What does 'Pop the top one or two values from the operand stack' mean? What would be an example when pop2 is used?

Comment: Have you checked how a long value could be popped of the stack? Maybe pop2 will serve this purpose.

Comment: @CoronA Could you give an example with code snippet?

Comment: `long` and `double` values occupy two slots on the operand stack. To remove them atomically `pop` instruction is not enogh - hence the special `pop2` instruction.

Comment: Two subsequent `pops` would work but would violate atomicity constraints, right?

Answer (score 5):

Write a small java program containing a main method with

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

do not use the result of this call. Then the bytecode looks like

```
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/System.currentTimeMillis()J
POP2
```

`System.currentTimeMillis()` puts a long value (64 bit, wide) on the stack. Yet this stack content is not used any more so it has to be popped such that other stack contents are reachable. 32 bit (normal size) need a simple `POP` and 64 bit (wide size)  need a `POP2`.

Answer (score 2):

> What does 'Pop the top one or two values from the operand stack' mean?

Think of it this way<sup>1</sup>:

- The `POP` bytecode pops a single value that occupies one x 32 bit word on the stack.
- The `POP2` bytecode either pops a single value that occupies two x 32 bit words, or two values that each occupies one x 32 bit word.

> What would be an example when `POP2` is used?

1. popping a `long` or `double` value; e.g. to discard an unwanted `long` result from a method call, or
2. popping two `int` values.

Note that *current generation* Oracle / OpenJDK `javac` compilers do not emit a `POP2` to pop 2 values.  If there are two 32 bit values on the stack that need to be popped, the compiler emits two `POP` instructions.  So, I can't give you an example of case #2 for ordinary Java code.  (But 3rd party compilers for Java or other languages might use it.  Or folks creating bytecodes some other way.)

I don't know enough about the JVM internals to be sure, but one likely reason for having `POP2` at all is that if you used two `POP` instructions to pop (say) a `long`, then part way through the sequence the stack would be in an invalid state.  That is liable to cause a verification error.

---

<sup>1 - This is not strictly correct.  The values on the stack are not strictly 32 or 64 bits.  For instance, a reference or return address on a 64 bit machine is 64 bits ... but it is still modeled as a category-1 value.  The explanation for this is that the bytecode instruction set was originally designed to be interpreted on 32 bit machines.</sup>

Comment: I assume POP2 is also used to ignore a double return value.

Answer (score 1):

POP: Pops the top single-word item off the stack and discards it.

POP2: Removes two single-word items from the stack (e.g. two integers, or an integer and an object reference) or one two-word item (i.e. a double or along).

The same javadoc mentioned in question conatins below info:

Table 2.3. Actual and Computational types in the Java Virtual Machine

```
Actual type Computational type      Category


1. byte             int               1
2. char             int               1
3. short            int               1
4. int              int               1
5. float            float             1
6. reference        reference         1
7. returnAddress    returnAddress     1
8. boolean          int               1
9. long             long              2
10. double          double            2
```

As you can see only long and double are of Category 2. This is because all other are computationally 32 bit while long and double are 64 bit.

The below example with make it clear.

```
public class PopVsPop2 {

public static int popint(){

    return  1;
}

public static long poplong() {
    return 1;
}


public static Long popLong() {
    return 1L;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    popint();
    poplong();
    popLong();
}
```

The above javacode has following generated bytecode:

```
public static main(String[]) : void
   L0
    LINENUMBER 24 L0
    INVOKESTATIC PopVsPop2.popint () : int
    POP
   L1
    LINENUMBER 25 L1
    INVOKESTATIC PopVsPop2.poplong () : long
    POP2
   L2
    LINENUMBER 26 L2
    INVOKESTATIC PopVsPop2.popLong () : Long
    POP
   L3
    LINENUMBER 27 L3
    RETURN
   L4
    LOCALVARIABLE args String[] L0 L4 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

As you can see

popint()- POP -Because int is of Category 1.

poplong() -POP2 - Because long is of Category 2. Same would be for double.

popLong()- POP- Because here Long refers to java.lang.Long which is a reference type. Hence of Category 1.